# How can evaluate an output of tcl file?

Tags: network-programming, tcl, simulation, ns2

I've been asked to do a simulation using NS for a single OSPF area and evaluate each result according to several criteria:

1. Control Traffic
2. CPU Processing Time
3. Convergence Time

I've done the simulation part, and here is one of the output files:
http://www.2shared.com/document/sDcr5Wmo/Single20.html

I couldn't paste it here, it's quite long :S

my question is:

how can I evaluate this output for the previous criteria?
like for example, in CPU Processing time, I've tried to open another terminal window and use

```
top -F -R -o cpu
```

to keep tracking the CPU usage when ns do run, I'm not sure this is true though :D

hope to find an answer here..

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking to evaluate according to the performance of the simulation itself, or of the system that is being simulated?

Comment: hmm I guess it's the first. what I need is to do the simulation for the same number of nodes but in multi areas, and I need to evaluate the result of Single vs. Multi area according the criteria in my question. So I have to evaluate each result and compare them. Thanks for ur response

Comment: I find that puzzling; I'd expect the performance of the system being simulated to be more important (unless you're developing the simulator itself, and not the simulation). I'm not convinced that “Control Traffic” makes sense otherwise… (BTW, I've never worked in network simulation so I don't know how to answer your question.)

Comment: if that so then it should be the second :D Thanks anyway Donal!

Answer (score 0):

You are not interested in the processor usage of the NS executable, this will not tell you anything about the processor usage of the OSPF area.

NS is an event based network simulator, so I doubt you can say anything about processor usage of the simulated systems with it.

However, if you know the behavior of the simulated systems, you can make some educated guesses. For example I would expect an increase in control traffic to result in more CPU usage.